# Error in writing compressed netcdf 4 files using raster in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster

I get an error message when writing compressed netcdf4 files using r raster package ver 2.5-2.

```
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(r, r*2)
writeRaster(s,"test.nc",format="CDF",compression=7)
```

Error:

```
 Error in R_nc4_create: Permission denied (creation mode was 4096)
```

or:

```
Error return from C call R_nc4_put_att_double for attribute _FillValue
```

Comment: I do not get this error, do you still get it?

Comment: No, I don't. It seems that the new version fixed the problem. Thanks anyways!